# NSArray to Description and vice versa

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have NSMutableArray like :

```
NSMutableArray *x=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",x.description);
```

From the description I got the following result :

```
(
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d
)
```

I want to again recreate the array from the description is it possible ?

Comment: @Kevin it is not json

Comment: Actually what is your real objective? To get a new array from existing array?

Comment: JSON would be a way to get a similar human readable description that you could use NSJSONSerialization class to go back and forth from the array and the description.  This will work if your data is composed of strings, numbers, arrays and dictionaries.

Comment: @Krishna I know the format `description` prints isn't json, but I think he's much better off looking into using json (in both directions) than trying to parse this himself.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way that would reliably work in all cases. For example, you cannot know if

```
(
    123
)
```

represents an array containing a string or a number.

**Added:** There actually *is* a method to convert the description back to an array object (but it does not always return an identical array for the reason given above). The  `description` method of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`
uses the [Old-Style ASCII Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001012-BBCBDBJE) format which can be read using `NSPropertyListSerialization`:

```
NSArray *a1 = @[@"123", @456];
NSString *desc = [a1 description];

NSData *d = [desc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSArray *a2 = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:d
                                                        options:0
                                                         format:NULL
                                                          error:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@", a2);
NSLog(@"a1[1] is a %@", [a1[1] class]);
NSLog(@"a2[1] is a %@", [a2[1] class]);
```

Output:

```
(
    123,
    456
)
a1[1] is a __NSCFNumber
a2[1] is a __NSCFString
```

As you can see, the array `a2` looks like `a1`, but the second element `456`, which was a `NSNumber` originally, has been read back as a `NSString`.

So you should use `description` only as a debugging tool. Better methods to create a reversible human-readable description or an archive have been mentioned in the other answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

While you *could*, it's not why NSLog() exists.  NSLog's purpose is to give a simple error logging mechanism for developers.

You should read into other means of [storing data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Topics&topic=Data%20Management) :

- Saving to file via NSData.
- Using Core Data
- NSCoder
- Various JSON serializers/parsers.
- etc.

But if you really want to, you could parse a log file manually. (With NSRegularExpressions perhaps, NSScanner, etc.)