# NSDictionary to NSDictionary formatted string and back

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, nsstring, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am trying to convert two formats of NSDictionary formatted strings to and from each other.

Both strings:

```
<key>info</key><dict><key>title</key><string>The Title</string></dict>
```

and

```
info = { title = "The Title";}
```

convert to an NSDictionary if I use `initWithData` or `initWithContentsofFile`. When I use `[NSDictionary description]` to get a string from a dictionary, I get the second string.
So it is a one way conversion if I input the first string. Is there an easy way to convert the second string back to the first and also use them together in a file like below and convert that to NSDictionary? Thanks.

```
<dict>
dict1 contents...
</dict>
info ={dict2 contents...}
```

Comment: **Do not use description** -- it's intended ONLY for debugging and its format can change at a moment's notice.  Either use the property list format or use JSON.

Comment: The `description` method of NSDictionary uses the so-called "Old-Style ASCII Property Lists format", and should only be used for debugging. - You *can* convert that back to some dictionary as demonstrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16783704/1187415 (that answer is for NSArray, but it works the same way for NSDictionary). But as said in that answer, you cannot distinguish between numbers and strings in the `description` output, therefore the reverse transformation does not always give the original dictionary.

Comment: @HotLicks, I am trying to keep the dictionary as the first type string, is this "property list format"? Do you mean that I can save nsdictionary directly to a plist file without `description`? 
I am currently saving by converting description string to NSData and then writing to a file. 

I am basically trying to save the dict to a plist file and retrieve it in the more readable form of the frist type of string. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinR, thanks for the link. 

In the linked question, one answer says to store to NSData. So I could convert the NSDictionary into NSData and store in a file. When retrieving the file, I would use NSDictionary `initWithContentsofFile` and this would return the same dict. Is there a way to convert this retrieved "dictionary object" to the easy readable format of the first string in the question or other human readable and editable formats (that keep the properties,etc, so not the _Old-Style ASCII_)?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem, many thanks to the comments.

To save in "human readable plist form"/"property list representation" (XML, etc) either use

- NSDictionary's `writeToFile:` method. [Doc link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a)

or

- NSPropertyListSerialization `dataWithPropertyList:` method. [Doc link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPropertyListSerialization/dataFromPropertyList%3aformat%3aerrorDescription%3a)

  ```
  NSError *error;    
  dataToBeStored = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:dictionaryToBeStored format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:&error];
  if (data) {
  NSFileManager* fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
  [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:dataToBeStored attributes:nil];
  [fileManager release];
  }
  ```

Now if you open the saved file up and read the data and convert to string you get a nice human readable plist. Or you can also `init` an NSDictionary with it.